# No resource limit detection when backing up data

Tags: database, backup, cnosdb

During the backup process, cnosdb reported a "Resources exhausted" error, and the backup did not stop quickly. Is this a bug? Is it more reasonable to add resource limit detection?

### 0. Env

```
version: cnosdb 2.3.3, 
revision: 54c8f4054b664ceb23bbb8609d495584f08ca488 
mode: single
```

### 1. Reproduce step

#### 1.1 Run cnosdb

```
docker run --name monitor -d -v /data/monitor/data/:/var/lib/cnosdb/ -v /data/monitor/cnosdb:/etc/cnosdb/  -v  /data/monitor/log/:/var/log/cnosdb/ -p 8902:8902 cnosdb/cnosdb-enterprise:enterprise-enterprise-2.3.4 cnosdb run --config /etc/cnosdb/cnosdb.conf -c 4 -m 8 -M singleton
```

NOTICE: There are about 40g data in the database.

#### 1.2 Backup

```
cnosdb-imexport export -s root:@127.0.0.1:8902 -p 'file:///etc/cnosdb/data'
```

#### 1.3 Check error

```
# Input args: Cli { subcmd: Export(ExportArgs { src: "root:@127.0.0.1:8902", path: "file:///etc/cnosdb/data", conn: None }) }
# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.cadvisor_version_info)  [Now: 13:46:17]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.cadvisor_version_info) data: [{"rows":211398}]

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_load_average_10s)  [Now: 13:46:17]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_load_average_10s) data: [{"rows":19154154}]

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_system_seconds_total)  [Now: 13:46:39]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_system_seconds_total) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: External error: Resources exhausted: Failed to allocate additional 8327600 bytes with 0 bytes already allocated - maximum available is 7959248"}

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_usage_seconds_total)  [Now: 13:46:48]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_usage_seconds_total) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: External error: Resources exhausted: Failed to allocate additional 8622696 bytes with 0 bytes already allocated - maximum available is 4478776"}

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_user_seconds_total)  [Now: 13:47:33]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_cpu_user_seconds_total) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: External error: Resources exhausted: Failed to allocate additional 5457328 bytes with 8065456 bytes already allocated - maximum available is 2614384"}

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_fs_inodes_free)  [Now: 13:47:34]
# Export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_fs_inodes_free) data: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: External error: Resources exhausted: Failed to allocate additional 5752424 bytes with 0 bytes already allocated - maximum available is 2439768"}

# Begin  export table(cnosdb.cadvisor.container_fs_inodes_total)  [Now: 13:47:35]
# Export  Data: Err("error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/sql?db=cadvisor&tenant=cnosdb): connection closed before message completed")
```